# How can i assign the redux state to react state while the redux state change in React-Redux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am update the redux state by triggering the action from a form component. The updated state will read from the mapStateToProps in the same Component. Now my question is how do i assign the updated redux state to the existing react state in the Component.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why would you want to do that? The components already have access to the updated props through `this.props`

Comment: @Kannaj Yes i have **this.props** in react but i need to access both the react and redux state for the same component with the condition either props or react state is true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`componentWillReceiveProps`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentwillreceiveprops) handler.

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextPropsFromRedux) {
  this.setState({ somethingFrom: nextPropsFromRedux.property})
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [setState](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#setstate) method of Component, and pass to it object with properties which were changed.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to do that, you probably want to you the `componentWillReceiveProps` component function and actually assign these values using `this.setState`.

But you have to be careful dealing with two application states. Ideally the component should only by able to receive props and transform or display them. In other words, we should avoid having component with state.

Take a look about [stateless components](https://hackernoon.com/react-stateless-functional-components-nine-wins-you-might-have-overlooked-997b0d933dbc).

Answer (score 0):

After mapStateToProps componentWillRecieveProps is called where you set your new state.

```js
/**
 * Created by consultadd on 22/2/17.
 */

import React, { Component } from 'react'
import Head from 'next/head'
import { Router } from '../../../routes'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'

export class EventOrderContainer extends Component {

  constructor (props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      orders: [],
      orderpage: 0,
      ShowCancel: false,
    }
  }
    componentWillRecieveProps(newProps){
    
    this.setState({
    orderpage:newProps.ordersPage})
    
    
    
    }

 

  render () {

    return (


    )
  }
}
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {

  return {
    ordersPage:state.orders.ordersPage
  }

  return state
}
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  
  
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(EventOrderContainer)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```